# c# keyboard hook works for only 10 times then it stops (or is supressed)?

Tags: c#, limit, keyboard-hook

It is the classic low level keyboard hook that I have used several times before quite successfully but lately it does not work right. It reads the keyboard inputs for exactly 10 times (10 times from any of the keys defined in HookCallback function) and then it stops. It is like some security feature of the OS or some other program like maybe an anivirus is getting in the way and  suppressing the keyboard hook after 10 times.

Has anyone else encountered this 10 times limit? What could be the problem, in your opinion? I am using Windows 7 64 Bit and avast free antivirus. The program is written in c# 2008.

Here is the relevant code from program.cs:

```
 static class Program
{

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);




    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }





    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                Form1.staticmethod1();
            }
            else if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.F8)
            {
                Form1.staticmethod2();
            }
            else if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.F9)
            {
                Form1.staticmethod3();
            }

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this one!

Comment: Are you doing anything funky inside those `Form1.staticmethodX()` methods?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code verbatim and I don't have this restriction. It works for me without fail. What version of Windows are you running and what keys are you pressing? Are you pressing the same key every time (F9 for example) or are you typing some crazy stuff?

Comment: Reading the comment from @Damien_The_Unbeliever also makes me think that it is possible that those form methods are blocking your callback. You should thread those if you can to allow your code to return your next hook ASAP

Comment: Windows protects itself from mis-behaving hook callbacks, it will automatically unregister the hook when the callback takes too long.  Default timeout is 5 seconds.  You are doing this wrong, use RegisterHotKey() instead.  Disabling the Delete key for all other programs is very unwise.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I assure you it is not some discrete keylogger/spyware that I am writing. It is the same code that I have used in several programs and it used to work before but it is not working in any of them now. It works fine in my old computer that has windows XP installed. It is giving problem in my 64 bit computer that runs IWndows 7 and also has Avast antivirus. So my guess is it has to be either of the two. I am not sure. The problem is not related to what is inside those Form1.staticmethods.

Comment: @Hans Passant, it is supressed after 10 times even if I press any other key defined in hookcallback like F9 or F8.

Comment: To users who are wondering if this program is about some keylogger/trojan... I do not prefer using third party tools like autohotkey etc. and I write my own tools for these things and this where codes like these come handy.

Comment: Customer on phone: "my brakes stops working after I step on them exactly 10 times".  Mechanic: "that can happen, you'll have to bring your car in so I can take a look under the hood".

Comment: I wasn't thinking it was a key logger. I was wondering along similar lines to what Brandon said - that you might be doing something that blocks or ties up resources, and its those resources that there are in fact 10 of. Maybe if you could add a sample of one of them to your question?

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. I did not post anything beyond the code in Pogram.CS because only this much seemed relevant because the static methods in Form1, even if I am calling them to show only a message box (MessageBox.Show()) or to sound a beep (Consolee.Beep(), it doesn't work. The functions are not called after 10 times at all. There are no loops and no huge resources consumed in a simple MessageBox.Show() or Console.Beep() methods. The hook is somehow blocked/unhooked after 10 times. And I am very curious to know where this 10 times limit is coming from.

Comment: Well I can't vouch for the 10 times, but Messagebox.Show() is a blocking call. I think I'm more leaning towards what @HansPassant said above about `RegisterHotKey()` and that you're probably approaching this incorrectly. Try this though: Press the key that calls the MessageBox.Show() function and wait 15 seconds before closing the messagebox. Then try to press a key again and see what happens.

Comment: Hans Passant is right. I have modified the code for use with RegisterHotKey and it works perfectly fine now. As for the 10 times limit, it was from Windows 7 for sure. I tested my old program in a virtual machine with a fresh install of Windows 7 and it gave the same problem.

Comment: If you totally empty out the static methods, except say increment a counter, and display the counter using a different thread, does the problem disappear? I encountered the same thing when using Windows hooks, in my case because my mouse handler was triggering itself recursively, which apparently Windows was smart enough to stop.